# How to retrieve an image (a jpg file) in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am  pretty new in C# and I have the following problem.

I have to retrieve an **hello.jpg** file that is into a subdirectory of my project.

So I think that I have to put the relative path into a string and the use this string to create an Image object or something like this.

Can you help me?

EDIT:

I have insert this code into my class:

```
private System.Web.HttpServerUtility server;

protected System.Drawing.Image _backgroundImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(server.MapPath("~/Path/Relative/To/Root.jpg"));
```

But I obtain the following error message:

> Error 76  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'PdfReport.iTextDocumentBase.server'  C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\PdfReport\iTextDocumentBase.cs  44  87  PdfReport
>   Error 77  A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field,
>   method, or property
>   'PdfReport.iTextDocumentBase.server'  C:\Develop\EarlyWarning\public\Implementazione\Ver2\PdfReport\iTextDocumentBase.cs  44  87  PdfReport

Why? what can I do to solve?

Comment: you want to display image in page?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: if your image name is hello.jpg why are you putting a path for Root.jpg?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Server.MapPath` to find the file, and `Image.FromFile` to load it:

```
var image = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/Path/Relative/To/Root.jpg"));
```

Do be careful with that, though - `Image` uses GDI+, which might not be the best on a web server.

This assumes that you want to use the image in server code, of course. If you want to display it to a client instead, you'd just use HTML, no server code necessary.

Comment: Two doubts:
1) Why do you use a var and not a specific type?
2) I have to èut this image inside a PDF that I am generating using iTextSharp (a library that generate PDF)

Comment: @AndreaNobili `var` is a specific type at runtime, it's just a syntax sugar - it is resolved during compilation, not runtime, and Visual Studio knows the proper type. Saves a lot on useless code repetition :) And yeah, if you need to put it inside a PDF, that's the code you'd use. Just make sure to dispose of the image as soon as possible (`image.Dispose();` as soon as you no longer need it).

Comment: mmm I am having some problem...now I edit my original post with your code and I explain what not work

Comment: @AndreaNobili Your class design is probably a bit chaotic, but you can use `HttpContext.Current.Server` or `HostingEnvironment.MapPath` instead if you don't have the `Server` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Store image path in lbllogo
lblLogo.Text = fuLogo.FileName.ToString();

Display the image using GetFileName
lblLogo.Text = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(imgLogo.ImageUrl);

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answers here are correct but it seems that there's a little bit confusion since your're new to this.

Here's what you have to do to resolve this:

- Create a new folder in your project, name the folder **Images**.
- Copy your **hello.jpg** image into the **Images** Folder.
- Now your image path is: **~/Images/hello.jpg**

Now in order to display your image into your page, you should create an Image control in your aspx page then display your **hello.jpg** image in it.

In your Page_Load event do this:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img.ImageUrl = "~/Images/hello.jpg";
        Page.Controls.Add(img);
    }
```

Again, the other answers are also correct but you need to change the URL in their answers to the correct URL of your image.

And also I've noticed that you were trying to create a `server` object in your code? you don't have to create a server object since you have it already in your Page control and can access it like this `Page.Server`.